# Fetching data from API and storing it to local database error

Tags: flutter, api, sqflite

I'm trying to store data that fetched from API using sqflite

Now I'm getting an error saying...

**A value of type 'List' can't be returned from the method 'getAllEmployees' because it has a return type of 'Future<List>'.**

Here's my *employee_provider.dart* file

```
class EmployeeApiProvider {
  Future<List<Employee>> getAllEmployees() async {
    var url = "http://demo8161595.mockable.io/employee";
    var response = await Dio().get(url);

    return employeeFromJson(response.data).map((employee) {
      DBProvider.db.createEmployee(employee);
    }).toList();
  }
}
```

How to fix this?

And other files relevant to this are...

*db_provider.dart*

```
class DBProvider {
  static Database? _database;
  static final DBProvider db = DBProvider._();

  DBProvider._();

  Future<Database?> get database async {
    if (_database != null) return _database;

    _database = await initDB();

    return _database;
  }

  initDB() async {
    Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final path = join(documentsDirectory.path, 'employee_manager.db');

    return await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onOpen: (db) {},
        onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
      await db.execute('CREATE TABLE Employee('
          'id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,'
          'email TEXT,'
          'firstName TEXT,'
          'lastName TEXT,'
          'avatar TEXT'
          ')');
    });
  }

  createEmployee(Employee newEmployee) async {
    await deleteAllEmployees();
    final db = await database;
    final res = await db!.insert('Employee', newEmployee.toJson());

    return res;
  }

  Future<int> deleteAllEmployees() async {
    final db = await database;
    final res = await db!.rawDelete('DELETE FROM Employee');

    return res;
  }

  Future<List<Employee>> getAllEmployees() async {
    final db = await database;
    final res = await db!.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE");

    List<Employee> list =
        res.isNotEmpty ? res.map((c) => Employee.fromJson(c)).toList() : [];

    return list;
  }
}
```

*employee_model.dart*

```
List<Employee> employeeFromJson(String str) =>
    List<Employee>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Employee.fromJson(x)));

String employeeToJson(List<Employee> data) =>
    json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class Employee {
  int id;
  String email;
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  String avatar;

  Employee({
    required this.id,
    required this.email,
    required this.firstName,
    required this.lastName,
    required this.avatar,
  });

  factory Employee.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Employee(
        id: json["id"],
        email: json["email"],
        firstName: json["firstName"],
        lastName: json["lastName"],
        avatar: json["avatar"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "email": email,
        "firstName": firstName,
        "lastName": lastName,
        "avatar": avatar,
      };
}
```

*home.dart*

```
class _HomeState extends State<AbcView> {
  var isLoading = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Api to sqlite'),
        centerTitle: true,
        actions: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0),
            child: IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.settings_input_antenna),
              onPressed: () async {
                await _loadFromApi();
              },
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0),
            child: IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
              onPressed: () async {
                await _deleteData();
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: isLoading
          ? const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            )
          : _buildEmployeeListView(),
    );
  }

  _loadFromApi() async {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });

    var apiProvider = EmployeeApiProvider();
    await apiProvider.getAllEmployees();

    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));

    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  _deleteData() async {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });

    await DBProvider.db.deleteAllEmployees();

    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));

    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  _buildEmployeeListView() {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: DBProvider.db.getAllEmployees(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        } else {
          return ListView.separated(
            separatorBuilder: (context, index) => const Divider(
              color: Colors.black12,
            ),
            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return ListTile(
                leading: Text(
                  "${index + 1}",
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                ),
                title: Text(
                    "Name: ${snapshot.data[index].firstName} ${snapshot.data[index].lastName} "),
                subtitle: Text('EMAIL: ${snapshot.data[index].email}'),
              );
            },
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to add `await` in front of the `DBProvider.db.createEmployee`?

```
class EmployeeApiProvider {
          Future<List<Employee>> getAllEmployees() async {
            var url = "http://demo8161595.mockable.io/employee";
            var response = await Dio().get(url);
        
            return employeeFromJson(response.data).map((employee) async {
             await DBProvider.db.createEmployee(employee);
            }).toList();
          }
        }
```